# Can't access method (Azure Tables with ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to access a method from another class (my controller for my view) where I make a connection to Azure Tables and update an entity.

My 'controller' makes a call as follows:

```
// this requires an object reference
HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = AzureTableConn.UpdateTenantSettings(post);
```

Here is my class containing my connection to Azure Tables where I pull my connection string from Azure Key Vault:

```
public class AzureTableConn
{
    public AzureTableConn(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    private CloudTable TableConnection(string tableName)
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration["AzureTableStorageConnectionString"];
        var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudTableClient tableClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable cloudTable = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
        return cloudTable;            
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateTenantSettings(TenantSettingsModel tenantSettingsModel)
    {
        CloudTable cloudTable = TableConnection("TenantSettings");
        Task<TableResult> mergeEntity = cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Merge(tenantSettingsModel));
        return new HttpResponseMessage();
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to call the `UpdateTenantSettings` method from my controller class but it says I need an instance. This makes sense however I can't create an instance without supplying an `IConfiguration` object to the default constructor. I feel like I'm caught in a catch 22 and don't know enough to get around it.

My intent is to use my `AzureTableConn` class across my application and not create new instances of it each time I want to read/write to Azure Tables. I've tried setting my `AzureTableConn` class to static and while this works around the object reference error, I get issues with my reference to `IConfiguration`. I've also tried setting my constructor to static but that breaks it again and tells me "a static constructor must be parameterless".

I've also tried adding the following to my `Startup.cs` file:

```
services.Configure<AzureTableConnectionString>(Configuration);
```

Where `AzureTableConnectionString` is defined as:

```
public class AzureTableConnectionString
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

However, I don't know if this is right or how to implement it.

So how can I pull my Azure Key Vault configuration settings inside a class, then use methods within the same class to re-use the connection to Azure Tables, and access those methods from another class where I need to provide parameters such as the entity (data) to create/update/delete/etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let ASP.NET Core handle this for you by registering `AzureTableConn` with the DI container, like this (in `ConfigureServices`):

```
services.AddSingleton<AzureTableConn>();
```

In order to use this in your controller(s), just add it as a parameter to the controller's constructor and store it for later use, like so:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly AzureTableConn _azureTableConn;

    public SomeController(AzureTableConn azureTableConn)
    {
        _azureTableConn = azureTableConn;
    }

    public IActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        ...
        var httpResponseMessage = _azureTableConn.UpdateTenantSettings(post);
        ...
    }
}
```

With this example, you can use `_azureTableConn` in any of your controller's actions. Because we've used `AddSingleton`, every controller will get the same instance, which will be created only once.

The docs do a good job of explaining this in much more detail: [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: Sorry, a little thick this morning. So if I understand this correctly, I'm basically creating a class which pulls in the `IConfiguration Configuration` still so I can use it inside that class, but the `AzureStorageConn` class gets created in startup with the singleton (one instance) command. You can then reference `AzureStorageConn`'s method's as you've shown above. I had to move around quite a bit of code to prevent breaking things but this looks like it will work!

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right. Now that you're not trying to depend on `AzureTableConn` as a static class, you need to pass the instances through DI using constructors, etc, so there's a few changes around that but your `AzureTableConn` should stay as-is at least. I've updated the answer with a specific example of referencing an `AzureStorageConn` method.

Comment: You can remove the dependency on `IConfiguration` from your `AzureTableConn` class using @Nkosi's approach, which is certainly worth considering too. I think there's an answer to your question that sits somewhere in between this answer and @Nkosi's answer that also removes said `IConfiguration` dependency but is lighter on overall abstraction.

Comment: Great, as I convert each method's reference from the old one I obviously need to add references to `AzureTableConn` in each one so I can use the `_azureTableConn` to get at the methods. Perfect. It's starting to make more sense now :)

Comment: Yeah - the downside of using DI is it's a little harder to actually get at instances (you need to pass them down, etc) but the upsides in terms of flexibility vastly outweigh that.

Answer (score 2):

Consider creating an abstraction.

```
public interface IAzureTableConnection {
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateTenantSettings(TenantSettingsModel tenantSettingsModel);
}
```

It is normally advised to avoid coupling to `IConfiguration`. Instead, get what you need to in the composition root and pass it to the dependent class.

`Startup`

```
private IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    //...

    var connectionString = Configuration["AzureTableStorageConnectionString"];
    var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
    CloudTableClient tableClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

    services.AddScoped<IAzureTableConnection>(_ => new AzureTableConnection(tableClient));

    //...
}
```

The dependent class would then only need to depend on configured `CloudTableClient`

```
public class AzureTableConnection: IAzureTableConnection {
    private readonly CloudTableClient tableClient;

    public AzureTableConnection(CloudTableClient tableClient) {
        this.tableClient = tableClient;
    }

    private CloudTable TableConnection(string tableName) {
        CloudTable cloudTable = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
        return cloudTable;            
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateTenantSettings(TenantSettingsModel tenantSettingsModel) {
        CloudTable cloudTable = TableConnection("TenantSettings");
        var mergeEntity = await cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Merge(tenantSettingsModel));

        //...do something with the result

        return new HttpResponseMessage();
    }
}
```

Your controller would depend on the `IAzureTableConnection` abstraction explicitly via constructor injection, and have access to the injected instance when needed

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    private readonly IAzureTableConnection tableConnection;

    public MyController(IAzureTableConnection tableConnection) {
        this.tableConnection = tableConnection;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction() {


        //...

        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await tableConnection.UpdateTenantSettings(post);

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful as well. I haven't created an interface before. Where does it go in you example (`public interface IAzureTableConnection`)?